# CSS: parent element float apply on <a> tag content too

Tags: html, css

this is HTML code:

```
<div class="pull-left small-text">
    <?php
        if($page - 1 > 0): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $page_link.'&p='.($page -1); ?>" class="btn btn-white"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    <?php
        endif; ?>
    <span><?php echo $page; ?> from <?php echo $pages; ?></span>
    <?php
        if($page < $pages) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $page_link.'&p='.($page +1); ?>" class="btn btn-white"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
    <?php
        endif; ?>
</div>
```

css:

```
.btn {
    border:none;
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.pull-left{
    float:left;
}
```

**problem:** when I add `pull-left` class to parent element , `<a>` tag icon goes left, It's what's happening:

[**result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzbH1.png)

note: pull-left = float:left;

Comment: Could you show us your CSS code?

Comment: @emjay thanks for comment , which class you want?

Comment: Post the rendered HTML please; the PHP is irrelevant

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add `display:inline-block` to `btn` class